# How get list of Databases using Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')?

Tags: python, adodb

I am using PIOLEDBENT provider, i need to extract list of databases in my PIAF Server when i call oConn.GetSchema i throws exception mention bellow. please guide me what is wrong with my code.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

oConn = Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
oRS = Dispatch('ADODB.RecordSet')
oConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=PIOLEDBENT; Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=True; Integrated Security=True;User ID=abubakr;Password=#Spark123!"
oConn.Open()
oConn.GetSchema();
```

Exception :

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'ADODB.Connection', u'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.', u'C:\\Windows\\HELP\\ADO270.CHM', 1240641, -2146825287), None)
```